# Has_many: :through for LineItems - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have four models:

- User
- Listing
- Order
- OrderGroup

#### User:

```
has_many :listings
has_many :orders
```

#### Listing:

```
belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
has_many :order_groups, through: :orders
has_many :orders
```

#### Order:

```
has_one :seller, through: :listing 
belongs_to :listing
belongs_to :order_group
```

#### OrderGroup:

```
has_many :listings, through: :orders
has_many :orders
has_many :sellers, through: :orders
```

When I try to pull `Order.where(seller: User.find(3))`, I get an empty collection. However, when I do `Order.last.seller`, I get the seller's user_id.

**How can I pull `Order.where(seller: User.find(3))'` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write query as

```
Order.joins(:listing).where('listings.user_id = ?', 3)
```